# Store selected table row into simple array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, submit

In my source code I create the following table...

```
echo "<form id=\"center\" Name=\"Form2\" Method=\"Post\" Action=\"\">";
    echo "<table border=\"1\">";
        foreach($pdo -> query($sqlSpielerNamen) as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style=\"font-size: 10;\">".$row['SpielerName']."</td>";
                echo "<td style=\"font-size: 10;\">".$row['Note']."</td>";
                echo "<td style=\"font-size: 10;\">".$row['Tore']."</td>";
                echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" id=".$row['Player_ID']." class=\"btn\" name=\"Add\" value=".$row['Player_ID']."></td><tr>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Now, I want to select a row via submit button. At the moment I get the `Player_ID` like this...

```
if(isset($_POST["Add"])){
    $P = $_POST["Add"];
}
```

But I need the whole row -- `Player_ID`, `Note` and `Tore` as well. 
I think a nice solution would be to write the row into an simple array. Something Like `array = ['Note', 'Tore', 'Player_ID']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include a hidden *input* field in each row comprising of all the details of the player(as a serialized string). Later, while processing the form, simply unserialize the string and get the player's details as an array. So you need to change your `foreach` loop in the following way,

```
// your code
foreach($pdo->query($sqlSpielerNamen) as $row){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 10;"><?php echo $row['SpielerName']; ?></td>
            <td style="font-size: 10;"><?php echo $row['Note']; ?></td>
            <td style="font-size: 10;"><?php echo $row['Tore']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="player_details[<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(serialize(array($row['SpielerName'],$row['Note'], $row['Tore']))); ?>">
                <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>" class="btn" name="Add" value="<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
// your code
```

Subsequently, after submission process your form in the following way,

```
if(isset($_POST["Add"])){
    $P = $_POST["Add"];
    list($SpielerName, $Note, $Tore) = unserialize($_POST['player_details'][$P]);
    // Now access $SpielerName, $Note and $Tore variables in your subsequent code
    ...
}
```

Here are the relevant references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: Thank you for this awesome explanation. But I have a last question. At the moment my button is filled with the player_id. But I want that every but should be named in Edit. How can I achieve that without losing the function?

Comment: @HansMuff It's quite simple, don't change the `id` attribute of *submit* input element, simply change the `value` attribute's value with player's name, like this: `<input type="submit" id="<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>" class="btn" name="Add" value="<?php echo $row['SpielerName']; ?>">`